# Static introspection of suitable hash function depending on type of hash key

Tags: c++, hash, hash-function

I'm looking for information regarding fast non-cryptographic hash functions designed for small keys (1-32 bytes). I'm especially interested in the context of system languages such as C++, D, Rust where different hash-function could be defaulted by the library through static introspection depending on the key type. For instance if I want to instantiate a hash set or hash map with a 32-bit or 64-bit integer as key, which hash function should I pick for that case (when mapping a 64-bit value to an unsigned integer bucket index).

Comment: Wouldn't the best algorithm depend on your anticipated distribution?

Comment: I guess so, but that information is normally not available during static introspection of my languages of interest.

Comment: Why the close vote?

Comment: But you know that the C++ standard library already includes hashes for many basic types? (I ask this because if you don't have a special distribution I would assume the standard committee has already made good choices. My answer would be to use those.)

Comment: I didn't vote to close, but without any more details, it seems like any standard algorithm would be fine. That's why I asked about anticipated distribution (which is language-neutral), e.g., what are you trying to hash--different types of data have different typical distributions.